# mvc model is not a strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model named operations  when i use it in my view it shows missing assembly reference.but it shows all other models except this(operations)

```
@model.medscreen.Models.operations
```

Comment: Remove the '.' after `@model`

Comment: tried it same error bro!!!

Comment: Then you haven't included enough information in your question. Please review [ask] and edit your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have a period between model and medscreen?

Try:

```
@model medscreen.Models.operations
```

Comment: but all other models are available as strongly typed except --operations